# Web API 2 routing not working after upgrading asp.net website to asp.net web app

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have an asp.net website type project that uses a few Web Api 2 controller. I converted it to an asp.net web application that supports all three technologies: webforms, web api and mvc.

The web api controllers have been moved by the converter (via Project -> Convert to Web Application) to a folder called Old_App_Code. They were in a App_Code/WebApi folder and now they are in Old_App_Code/WebApi. All the controllers with the exception of one were in a namespace, let's call it name1.name2.name3:

```
namespace name1.name2.name3
{
  [RoutePrefix("api/v1/orders")]
  public class OrdersController : BaseAppController //BaseAppController is a class that inherits ApiController and adds a few common methods to all WebApi controllers ...
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

WebApiConfig.cs (under Old_App_Code):

```
namespace name1.name2.name3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// </summary>
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {            
          config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();//use attributes to map routes.

        }
    }
}
```

global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{


  GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;

  // Code that runs on application startup
  log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

  AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
  //      GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
  GlobalConfiguration.Configure(name1.name2.name3.WebApiConfig.Register);
  FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
  RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
  BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

}
```

RouteConfig.cs:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
  public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
  {
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
  }
}
```

The problem that I have is that the web api routing doesn't work anymore, I get 404s.

I used the ApiHelp page and the only controller registered is the one that didn't have a namespace to begin with. I put it in a namespace hoping that it won't show up (to get some consistency :-) ), but it still shows up (I restarted IIS Express).

Somehow, MapHttpAttributeRoutes doesn't seem to find these controllers to build the web api routes from.

Any ideas?

I am using VS 2015 with version 5.2.3.0 of System.Web.Mvc and Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi 5.2.3.

**Update**: The controller that works inherits directly from ApiController while the other controllers inherit from a common class (which inherits ApiController) that is in a different project and it is used in another app. Is there a way to tell the component that registers the controllers that these are WebApi controllers as well? I update the code snippet above to reflect this.

Comment: Are OldAppCode and AppCode two independent projects?

Comment: @PrashanthBenny Please note that they are App_Code and Old_App_Code. App_Code is a special folder in the website type projects that contains code, for example it contains web api controllers. When the website was converted to a web app, App_Code is renamed to Old_App_Code.

Comment: You didn't Register your WebApiConfig inside Application_Start. You have it commented out

Comment: @K.AlanBates: It was actually replaced with `GlobalConfiguration.Configure(name1.name2.name3.WebApiConfig.Register);`

Comment: @costa oh...didn't notice that....so is your application starting up? (I understand you're not routing, but are you at least able to start the application in Cassini?)

Comment: Also, do you actually have any RouteAttributes defined inside your controller?  You represented your controller internals with an ellipsis, and you only show your RoutePrefix

Comment: @K.AlanBates: Yes. See my own answer. It turns out it was an issue with versions.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The project where the BaseAppController was created referenced version 5.2.2 of the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core (and the additional libraries) while the main web application referenced version 5.2.3. As soon as I changed the reference to 5.2.3 in that project, the controllers were registered properly.

Comment: ...that can do it. Glad you were able to get it straightened out.  I've had that happen before when installing package sub-dependencies end up crossing the WebApi versions up.